# Как получить все уникальные атрибуты у коллекции через связь many-to-many?

Tags: laravel, коллекции, eloquent

Кажется я написал в вопросе чушь)) Но постараюсь объяснить подробнее.
Реализую на laravel.
Мне нужно получить все доступные атрибуты "цвет" у коллекции товаров.
Я делаю вот так (связь многие-ко-многим через промежуточную таблицу):

```
$colors = $products->pluck('colors')
   ->unique();
```

Но так не работает. Потому как в таком случае unique применяется к первым вложенным коллекциям (а то сами товары), а у каждого товара своя вложенная коллекция атрибута "цвет".

То есть, если вызвать dd($products), то получаю так (Лишнее убрал для читабельности):

```
Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator {#1594 ▼
  #total: 7
  #items: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1814 ▼
    #items: array:7 [▼
      0 => App\Models\Product {#1681 ▼
        #fillable: array:17 [▶]
        ...
        #attributes: array:20 [▶]
        ...
        #relations: array:9 [▼
          "colors" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1760 ▼
            #items: array:2 [▼
              0 => App\Models\Color {#1782 ▼
                ...
                #attributes: array:12 [▼
                  "id" => 1
                  "name" => "синий"
                  "title" => "siniy"
                ]
              ...
              1 => App\Models\Color {#1778 ▼
                ...
                #attributes: array:12 [▼
                  "id" => 3
                  "name" => "красный"
                  "title" => "krasnyy"
                ]
              ...
      1 => App\Models\Product {#1649 ▶}
...
```

У каждого товара есть цвет. У кого-то указан, у кого-то не указан, у кого-то указано несколько.
Мне нужно получить уникальные цвета (с id, title, name) без повторений.

Как мне правильно это реализовать?

Comment: Может вы что-то не так делаете, раз у 1 товара цвета дублируются? Лучше причину исправлять, а не следствие

Comment: Нет, это же ведь не 1 товар. Я получаю список товаров по категории. К примеру их 5. У каждого есть цвета: у первого - синий и красный, у второго - красный, у третьего черный, у четвертого и пятого не указаны. Вот мне надо получить все доступные цвета без дублирования.

Comment: Тогда или это  2 запроса (2й, условно, Color::whereHas('products')->unique()->get()), или форычем проходиться по товарам и в новый массив собирать цвета

Comment: @InDevX Ну это понятно. Но атрибутов то много. Не только цвет, а еще плюс с десяток. И дополнительные запросы будут только излишней нагрузкой. При вызове ($colors = $products->pluck('colors')->unique()) я получаю эти данные, просто необходимо каким-то образом собрать уникальные. Я уверен, что это стандартная задача и решение есть элементарное, но почему-то найти не могу нигде.

Comment: Просто создай коллекцию и там обработай все нужное тебе. Либо у полученной модели есть метод ->map(), и в нем кожу элемент собрать в отдельный массив. Все ещё просто не понятна задача. Что мы хотим в конце получить?

Comment: Решение оказалось таким: `$availableColors = $products->pluck('colors') ->filter(function($value, $key) {  return  $value != '[]';  }) ->collapse() ->sortBy('name') ->unique('title');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$availableColors = $products->pluck('colors')
            ->filter(function($value, $key) {
                return  $value != '[]';
            })
            ->collapse()
            ->sortBy('name')
            ->unique('title');
```